# Are .Net Queues thread safe if only one thread is reading data?

Tags: c#, concurrency

I am working on a system where multiple threads can enqueue operations, but only thread will be dequeuing those operations to perform business logic on them.

What are the any ramifications of using a regular .net `Queue` (instead of a `ConcurrentQueue`) in this scenario?

Comment: Queue is not thread-safe, end of story.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Your software will break and terrible things will happen. You're reading and writing from different threads. Use a ConcurrentQueue. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: As I can obviously use the concurrent queue I'm more interested in the why

Comment: The "why" is an implementation detail. It's just not designed to be so. It's best to heed the docs on this one:  "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." (***particularly*** with concurrent reads and writes).

Comment: @KallDrexx, as to why, it's because by default mutating state is not thread-safe.  Since the stock queue doesn't indicate it *is* thread safe, it is naturally not.